# Android crash executing C++ code not replicable with adb shell

Tags: android, c++, crash, logcat, crash-dumps

I'm struggling with a bad kind of crash in my application and I'm losing also the little hair I have left.

The issue is: if I execute my program (written in C++ 11) through adb shell, there is **NO** crash. But still I get a SIGSEGV both on eclipse emulator and my device.

I must execute this program though a simple app:

Android App code:

```
public BufferedReader startExample() {
    String[] commandLine2 = {"/system/app/example", "/system/app/conf.xml"};

    System.out.println("Example launched with "+currentScript);

    Process process = null;

    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine2);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));   
        writer = new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return reader;
}
```

The output I receive on my Logcat is this:

```
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65): Build fingerprint: 'google/passion/passion:2.3.6/GRK39F/189904:user/release-keys'
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65): pid: 2573, tid: 2573  >>> /system/app/example <<<
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):  r0 00000027  r1 deadbaad  r2 a0000000  r3 00000000
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):  r4 00000001  r5 00000000  r6 001405d4  r7 00144838
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):  r8 000eb53c  r9 00000000  10 00000000  fp beba99b4
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):  ip afd46668  sp beba97f8  lr afd191d9  pc afd15ca4  cpsr 60000030
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):  d0  6772615f64696c75  d1  206e69687469776d
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):  d2  7574706163206f65  d3  6874206e6f20656e
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):  d4  2030202020203020  d5  2020203020202020
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):  d6  3020202020202020  d7  2020202020202020
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):  d16 bfa11178a5a14a1b  d17 bfa0c9714fbcda40
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):  d18 bfa0e1b8218a374c  d19 bf91111111111116
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):  d20 0000000000000000  d21 3fd99999ac013de9
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):  d22 3fd24924a3334279  d23 3fcc71c536ee839c
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):  d24 3fc74664af50539d  d25 3fc39a09d078c69f
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):  scr 00000010
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):          #00  pc 00015ca4  /system/lib/libc.so
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):          #01  lr afd191d9  /system/lib/libc.so
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65): code around pc:
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65): afd15c84 2c006824 e028d1fb b13368db c064f8df 
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65): afd15c94 44fc2401 4000f8cc 49124798 25002027 
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65): afd15ca4 f7f57008 2106ec7c edd8f7f6 460aa901 
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65): afd15cb4 f04f2006 95015380 95029303 e93ef7f6 
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65): afd15cc4 462aa905 f7f62002 f7f5e94a 2106ec68 
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65): code around lr:
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65): afd191b8 4a0e4b0d e92d447b 589c41f0 26004680 
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65): afd191c8 686768a5 f9b5e006 b113300c 47c04628 
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65): afd191d8 35544306 37fff117 6824d5f5 d1ef2c00 
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65): afd191e8 e8bd4630 bf0081f0 00028344 ffffff88 
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65): afd191f8 b086b570 f602fb01 9004460c a804a901 
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65): stack:
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):     beba97b8  afd42664  
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):     beba97bc  00147930  
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):     beba97c0  0000001a  
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):     beba97c4  afd182a1  /system/lib/libc.so
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):     beba97c8  afd4270c  
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):     beba97cc  afd426b8  
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):     beba97d0  00000000  
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):     beba97d4  afd191d9  /system/lib/libc.so
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):     beba97d8  00000001  
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):     beba97dc  beba980c  
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):     beba97e0  001405d4  
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):     beba97e4  00144838  
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):     beba97e8  000eb53c  /system/app/example
05-26 16:13:45.680: I/DEBUG(65):     beba97ec  afd184fb  /system/lib/libc.so
05-26 16:13:45.690: I/DEBUG(65):     beba97f0  df002777  
05-26 16:13:45.690: I/DEBUG(65):     beba97f4  e3a070ad  
05-26 16:13:45.690: I/DEBUG(65): #00 beba97f8  0000000a  
05-26 16:13:45.690: I/DEBUG(65):     beba97fc  afd1c80f  /system/lib/libc.so
05-26 16:13:45.690: I/DEBUG(65):     beba9800  0000000a  
05-26 16:13:45.690: I/DEBUG(65):     beba9804  afd426b8  
05-26 16:13:45.690: I/DEBUG(65):     beba9808  001405d4  
05-26 16:13:45.690: I/DEBUG(65):     beba980c  fffffbdf  
05-26 16:13:45.690: I/DEBUG(65):     beba9810  05000000  
05-26 16:13:45.690: I/DEBUG(65):     beba9814  afd42610  
05-26 16:13:45.690: I/DEBUG(65):     beba9818  00000001  
05-26 16:13:45.690: I/DEBUG(65):     beba981c  000eb654  /system/app/example
05-26 16:13:45.690: I/DEBUG(65):     beba9820  0013fe40  
05-26 16:13:45.690: I/DEBUG(65):     beba9824  00000000  
05-26 16:13:45.690: I/DEBUG(65):     beba9828  0000004e  
05-26 16:13:45.690: I/DEBUG(65):     beba982c  0013fe40  
05-26 16:13:45.690: I/DEBUG(65):     beba9830  00000055  
05-26 16:13:45.690: I/DEBUG(65):     beba9834  0000004e  
05-26 16:13:45.690: I/DEBUG(65):     beba9838  00000047  
05-26 16:13:45.690: I/DEBUG(65):     beba983c  000ad0a0  /system/app/example
05-26 16:13:45.710: I/BootReceiver(96): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_05 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
```

I've already searched through stackoverflow and the Internet, but no Q/A fits my problem.
I think it could be caused by some kind of error in memory management APIs in C++ code but I'm confused since launching the program with adb shell gives no error at all.

Do you have any idea about I should proceed to fix this? Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
The old dear manual debug is always the best (even if a little too slow).
For those who will have a similar trouble:

```
m_source = pcap_open_live(name.c_str(),BUFSIZ,1 ,10,errbuf);
if(!m_source) {
    throw(std::invalid_argument("TcpPcapSource::error within pcap_open_live"));
}
```

the crash was occurring at throw command. pcap wants the program to be run with superuser's priviledges and I was using a bad command.
As soon as I made the App execute the program with su/sudo (depending on your adb version), the error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

How about gradually cutting things out of your C++ code until the error disappears.  That way you'll be able to locate the area of code that causes the problem.  I know it's a painfully slow approach, but that's probably what I'd feel forced to do in your situation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm doing that right now but I wanted to post my question doing so because I think somebody with sufficient debugging experience could figure it out at least where should I look for

Answer (score 1):

This is error is a segmentation fault:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSEGV

A segmentation fault (often shortened to segfault), bus error or access violation is generally an attempt to access memory that the CPU cannot physically address. (i.e. an equivalent to null pointer exception)

The following are some typical causes of a segmentation fault:

- Attempting to execute a program that does not compile correctly. Some compilers will output an executable file despite the presence of compile-time errors.
- Dereferencing NULL pointers
- Attempting to access memory the program does not have rights to (such as kernel structures in process context)
- Attempting to access a nonexistent memory address (outside process's address space)
- Attempting to write read-only memory (such as code segment)
- A buffer overflow
- Using uninitialized pointers

So you should search your code for locations where you might have done some of the errors above!

Comment: When you're dealing with 50+ K lines of code and you can't use your debugger (because of the cross-compilation stuff) it's a bit rough :P
+1 for the useful remainder though